# React component not rendering in the parent

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

I'm trying to render Justin.js into, Home.js (see screenshot below). It's not my first go around with React.js, so I dont understand why it's not rendering when I include it as a element in the parent. My route is defined properly as well, because it does render the static markup in Home.js perfectly fine. I am using server side rendering, but I was working just fine on all my other pages except this one (check out the link from my Github for my boiler plate that im using https://github.com/js1599/gulp. Any help would be appreciated, been stuck here for a day

Screenshot: 
[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the className of "who" can't be reference to by it's name while within another file. So what you have to do is just Import the component as usual, and then use the name you imported it as, as the element name. See Screenshot below. [image]

Here's Another Screenshot for more explanation

[image]